# how to move mysql database or data directory to another location

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using MySQL Database for my django application.The data is stored in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\Data\` by default.

1. So it is possible to move the data folder any other location/drive.I am using Innodb.
2. How to keep database directory of different databases at a different location?

PS:Now I suppose I have solved the question.

1. If you want to move the database directory to different location follow Bakkal's answer. Use Symlinks.
2. If you just want to move the data dir to different location follow my answer.

Also read about [innodb-file-per table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html).It may be useful if you want to separate table data and indexes.

Comment: There is no such thing as the "mysql database file".

Comment: I mean data folder by that.Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although MySQL is not meant to operate like that (unlike file based databases), you could symlink the database folder into a folder on your project folder (There's no point in putting your sqlite file or DB folder inside your virtualenv, doesn't make sense)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/symbolic-links.html

Comment: Thanks a lot.Your answer helped me :).But I actually want to move whole data folder as if I use symlink data still goes in the ibdata1 file.I edited my question now may be it was not much clear before.I got the answer now.Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

To change the location of the MySQL data folder follow these steps:

1. Close Mysql server.
2. Open task manager and kill mysqld-nt.exe process if its running.
3. Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0` .
4. Move `data` folder from here to the desired location.
5. Now again do step 3 and open `my.ini` as adminstrator and update the `datadir='pathtodata/data/'`and save the file.
6. Done!